# Java check if string only contains english keyboard letters

Tags: java, string, character

I want to disallow users from using any special characters in their name.
They should be able to use the whole english keyboard, so

```
a-z, 0-9, [], (), &, ", %, $, ^, °, #, *, +, ~, §, ., ,, -, ', =, }{
```

and so on. So they should be allowed to use every "normal" english character which you can type with your keyboard.

How can I check that?

Comment: by writing code that does that. It's pretty easy to make a rudimentary check like that, but it does involve coding a bit.

Comment: Funny. I don't really know how to do that. The only way I'd do that is replacing all characters from the keyboard (like (), {}, -, + etc) and then using StringUtils isAlphanumeric Method. Is there no more efficient way?

Comment: try `String` `matches()`.

Comment: And what regex do I have to use then?

Comment: Marco, it should contain numbers or any other characters from the english keyboard. If I wanted to check if it is numeric or alphanumeric, I'd never have asked here

Comment: Regex, that consists of choice of characters you presented. If you don't know regex you can do huge if for each character..

Comment: When you write "English keyboard" I take it you mean a British keyboard? The American keyboard does not have a key for `§` for example

Comment: § does not AFAIK exist on a British keyboard either.

Comment: @user13784117 top left corner, under escape https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22B/A/magic-keyboard-british-english

Comment: Oh, an Apple keyboard,, not a PC keyboard.  Which demonstrates that there's no such thing as a standard British keyboard.  I wonder whether the OP wants his "every character you can type with your keyboard" to have to consider what kind of keyboard it is?

Comment: Your requirement needs to be more precise. You would be better off specifying what characters are permitted.  And do you really want characters like `[`,`]`,`*`, et al in the user names?

Comment: What do you have against somebody with the name O'Maley?

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?  Who cares what characters are in the name?  Is your code in any way affected if someone puts an infinity symbol in there?

Answer (score 2):

We can do like:

```
String str = "My string";
System.out.println(str.matches("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]+$"));//true

str = "My string1";
System.out.println(str.matches("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]+$"));//false
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want that users can use the whole english keyboard, so every character you can type with a english keyboard. Other characters, like for example any acsii characters or chinese letters should not be allowed.

Comment: *any acsii characters … should not be allowed.*  (1) Java uses Unicode, so there are no ASCII characters involved, (2) but if you mean "characters that are also present in ASCII" then, uh, "A, B, C..." are ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use **regex** to match name with English alphabets.

Solution 1:

```
if(name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
  // Accept name
}
else {
  // Ask to enter again
}
```

Solution 2:

```
while(!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
  // Ask to enter again
}
// Accept name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java) for this.

Since you have lots of characters that have special meaning in a regular expression, I recommend putting them in a separate string and quoting them:

```
String specialCharacters = "-[]()&...";
Pattern allowedCharactersPattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9" + Pattern.quote(specialCharacters) +  "]*");

boolean containsOnlyAllowedCharacters(String str) {
    return allowedCharactersPattern.matcher(str).matches();
}
```

As for how to obtain the string of special characters in the first place, there is no way to list all the characters that can be typed with the user's current keyboard layout. In fact, since there are ways to [type any Unicode character at all](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0) such a list would be useless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I find the requirement to be quite strange , in that I can't see the rationale behind accepting `§` but not, say, `å`, and I have not checked the list of characters you want to accept in any detail.

But, it seems to me that what you're asking is to accept any character whose codepoint value is less than 0x0080, with the oddball exception of `§` (0x00A7).  So I'd code it to make that check explicitly, and not get involved with regular expressions.  I assume you want to exclude control characters, even though they can be typed on an English keyboard.

Pseudocode:

```
 for each character ch in string
      if ch < 0x0020 || (ch >= 0x007f && ch != `§')
           then it's not allowed
```

Your requirements are oddly-stated though, in that you want to disallow "special characters" but allow `!@#$%6&*()_+' for example.  What's your definition of "special character"?

For arbitrary definition of 'allowable characters' I'd use a bitset.

```
static BitSet valid = new Bitset();
static {
    valid.set('A', 'Z'+1);
    valid.set('a', 'z'+1);
    valid.set('0', '9'+1);
    valid.set('.');
    valid.set('_');
      ...etc...
}
```

then

```
for (int j=0; j<str.length(); j++)
    if (!valid.get(str.charAt(j))
        ...illegal...
```